# Words marked as 'rare' in .add file are not always highlighted as such

Tags: spell-checking

I'm trying to create a list of 'rare' words as a supplementary spellfile so

- I have created `list.utf-8.add` and used `mkspell!` to create `list.utf-8.add.spl`
- I included `list.utf-8.add` in my spellfile setting

If I append `/!` to every word to mark it as 'bad', the highlighting works as expected (every word is highlighted per `SpellBad`.)

However, if I append `/?` instead to every word to mark it as 'rare', the words are not highlighted at all. I verified that `SpellRare` is correctly configured.

What am I missing?

===

Adding more information:

What I am trying to do is use my tags file to create a spellfile that will highlight identifiers and such in comments as 'rare' words. Since these are identifiers and not natural language words, they have 'unusual' characteristics, such as embedded underscores.

After further experimentation, I have found that a few identifiers from the list do get highlighted with `SpellRare`, but most don't get highlighted at all and others have parts highlighted as `SpellBad`.

In detail:

- If the words in the list are marked as 'valid' (i.e., no flags), then the spell check considers them valid and they are not highlighted
- If the words in the list are marked as 'bad' (i.e., `/!` flag), then the spell check considers them bad and they are highlighted with `SpellBad`
- If the words in the list are marked as 'rare' (i.e, `/?` flag), then "it depends"

  - If the first part of the word up to a '_' is not a valid natural language word then the whole word is marked as 'rare' and highlighted with `SpellRare`
  - Otherwise, each part of the word (delimited by '_') is considered valid or not on its own depending on whether it is a valid natural language word or not, and highlighted accordingly

Comment: I observed something very similar. In my case I can flag the strings `par ex.` and `p.ex.` as good words, or as bad words, but flagging them as rare words would not work. With what you wrote, I suspect this is due to the presence of a non-word character in the middle of them. Looks like a Vim bug to me, did you consider reporting it?

Comment: More tests: if I flag `xxx.yyy` as bad, then it is always shown as bad as a whole (i.e. the dot is highlighted too), which is the expected outcome, If I rather flag it as good/rare, then it is generally shown as good/rare *but* if the word gets highlighted for another reason (missing capital), then only the first part gets the special highlighting (the capitalization warning) while the 2nd part is shown as wrong. Weirder: in that situation, if I let the cursor run over the word, then highlighting switches to the correct outcome! And conversely if I go back! Definitely a bug I’d say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this problem after a long hiatus.

The solution is to switch from "word list" format to Myspell format, and define '_' as a mid-word character by putting the line

```
MIDWORD _
```

in the .aff file, along with

```
RARE ?
```

to specify that (for example) '?' will be used to flag "rare" words in the .dic file.